# Git and Dos - how to exit a command

Tags: git, dos

This is hopefully a very simple question:

I typed "git log"

A bunch of commits came up, and by hitting Enter it will scroll down to show me more.  How can I exit from the git log command without scrolling through the entire history?

Comment: Please give information about what operating system you are using, and what kind of terminal you are using. For example, if you're using Windows, are you using Cygwin, msysgit Bash, Posh Git powershell, or the regular CMD terminal that Windows provides?

Answer (score 3):

hit `q`

Please correct your facts though. You are not working in `DOS`. This is only a terminal emulator of your operating system (most probably ms windows). FYI there are better operating systems out there.

update: git uses a pager (on my system `less` but perhaps depends on system it might be `more`) so output doesn't disappear past screen end. `q` is a command making these pagers quit.

Comment: Why not explain a little bit about what `q` does? That way, you don't have to add padding ;)

Comment: @ChrisForrence, on your command